# If the density of a solid sphere decreases with its radius, at what radius is the density same as the average density?

Tags: calculus, geometry, spheres

Suppose the density of a solid sphere is given by the following equation $$\rho=R-r$$

where $r \leq R$. This means the density of the sphere decreases as we go from its center to its surface

We know the total mass of the sphere is $M$, and total volume is $V=\frac{4}{3}\pi R^3$, the average density is $\rho_{avg}=\frac{M}{V}$

Then, at what $r$ value does $\rho =\rho_{avg}$?

Comment: where $\frac{M}{V} = R - r$

Comment: and $M = \iiint \rho ~dV = \iiint (R-r) ~dV$

Comment: Are these two statements equivalent?

Comment: What do you mean? First find $M$ and then use the first equation to find $r$ where $\rho = \rho_{avg}$

Comment: What are $r$ and $R$?

Comment: At $R_{ave.}=\frac{R+r}2$ we have average density which is $\frac M{R_ave}$.